# Is there a way to save and accsess data in a bookmarklet?

Tags: javascript, database, bookmarklet

I'm looking for something similar to local storage but associated with the bookmarklet itself rather than the current page. I know I could just store cookies on the current page but, unfortunately, the bookmarklet will be used on multiple pages. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I just skimmed the other post :). I've edited it now.

Comment: If the answer is the same then it is a duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the bookmarklet runs in the context of the current page, there's no standard web storage mechanism (including cookies) that will let you maintain information for the bookmarklet rather than for the page it's used on.

To do this, you'll have to store information on a server, and ajax calls to it, with CORS enabled to allow those calls from the various pages where the bookmarklet may be used.